# How to receive all the details of the order using WooCommerce( Paypal)?

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm currently working on the Wordpress Project (WooCommerce). When a client buys a product, i receive a short message from Wordpress and one short message from Paypal, both of these messages contain only the price.

I would like for these messages to contain all of the information related to my client's order like amount, description of products etc.

How can i do it?

Comment: Are you overriding the email templates from your theme? By default you get a list of all the products purchased, in addition to their prices, quantities, the total for the order, shipping costs, etc.

Comment: no i wasn't changing the default template